# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'plugin' of undefined while uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working with an html template. it is fine in local xampp installation. But when uploaded to server it doesn't show any images at all. and console shows 2 errors
`Uncaught TypeError: f.cookie is not a function`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'plugin' of undefined`

How do i mitigate this bug

Comment: this seems there are some js files link wrong and they pointed to the localhost

Comment: The thing is that the template does not use any php. it is working fine in xampp but when i open index file out side from the server(Not using localhost) the template becomes blank

Comment: does it have any external js files